# Is ti possible to detect suggested word on smartphone (windows phone) with angular or js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone, swipe

When WP user opens some webpage, and types in html input field using swipe or regular keyboard, he gets suggested words above the keyboard. If he selects one of suggested words, chosen word appears in input field, but it is neither recognized by model nor form-control (input field stays untouched, and input field's value stays unchanged).
Is there any way to detect chosen word with angular/js?